# Solve a fourth order differential equation

Tags: finite-difference, integral-equations

I want to solve
$$
\frac{\partial^2}{\partial t^2}u(z,t) + a\frac{\partial^2}{\partial z^2}u(z,t) + k\frac{\partial^4}{\partial z^4}u(z,t) = 0 
$$

with $u(z,0) = 1+0.1e^{-\frac{z^2}{2}}$. I'd like to study the dynamic of the wave.

What is the simplest way to do it?

I tried with the finite difference method but my solution diverges very quickly!

I use this iteration

$$
f_j^{n+1} = 2f_j^n - f_j^{n-1} + \frac{\Delta t^2}{\Delta z^2}a(f_{j+1}^n - 2f_j^{n} + f_{j-1}^n) +k \frac{\Delta t^2}{\Delta z^4}(f^n_{j-2}-4f^n_{j-1}+6f^n_{j}-4f^n_{j+1} + f^n_{j+2})
$$
where $n$ it's the time step and $j$ the space step.

Improving my question after comments:

I used a very small time step and this is what I obtain:

[image: shock]

How can avoid the reflection with this iteration method?

Comment: What are your boundary conditions?

Comment: I don't have a lot of information about the derivatives... It's simple to calculate $\frac{\partial }{\partial z}u(z,0)$ but for the time derivative i don't have any infomation.

Comment: This is a wave equation with an extra term. I've to use the typical boundary condition

Comment: OK - they probably aren't the issue on second glance.  You may just need to use an incredibly small timestep?  A rough guess is that fourth order equations imply a CFL condition of $\Delta t < C\frac{\Delta z^2}{\sqrt{k}}$ for some constant $C$.

Comment: I believe for a 4th order equation it's even worse, $\Delta t < \mathcal{O}(\Delta z^4)$. Either use a REALLY small time step or an implicit method.

Comment: I think since it's a second order wave equation in time, it's only $\Delta z^2$ (factor of $\Delta t^2$ multiplies the operator instead of $\Delta t$).  If it was the *beam* equation, then we'd talking CFL condition of $O(\Delta z^4)$. Also, how do you do that script $O$?

Comment: The time step is of course $\Delta t = O(\Delta z^2)$. It is determined by the eigenvalues of the iteration matrix which is determined by the largest eigenvalue of the spatial discretization matrix which is determined by the order of the differential operator, i.e., $O(\Delta z^{-4})$. But it is multiplied by $\Delta t^2$. The product must remain bounded, yielding $\Delta t = O(\Delta z^2)$.

Comment: Thank you guys! I used a small time step and the result is in the question. I have reflections... do you have any idea to delete them?

Comment: Reflections are likely a result of your boundary conditions - can you specify them?

Comment: Sure. My space is divided in $n$ space-step, the last one is labeled $n-1$. My condition are:
-) When the function $f_{j+2}$ could not be calculated because $j=n-1$ or $j=n-2$, i use for $f_{j+2}$ the value $f_2$ and $f_1$ respectively. And it's the same for other values $f_{j+k}$ where i can't calculated due to the finite space. I don't know if i'm clear.

Comment: @JLC do you think my result is correct?

Comment: I think your boundary conditions are causing reflections, but I'm not too familiar with boundary conditions for acoustic waves. You might google "non-reflecting boundary conditions" for acoustics and see what pops up.

Comment: @JLC thank you! i'll do it! I tried to change the value of $a$ form $0.000025$ to $0.4$ but the velocity of the wave changes a little bit...

Comment: @JLC the script O is just `\mathcal{O}`

Answer (score 5):

You haven't specified boundary conditions, but it sounds like you want to solve the Cauchy problem (i.e., the initial value problem on the whole real line $\infty < z < \infty$).

In that case, there is no need to use finite differences.  You can simply use Fourier analysis (separation of variables) to write down the exact answer.  Once you have that, you can evaluate it numerically by truncating the domain and the set of Fourier modes.

If you insert the ansatz

$$u(z,t) = \exp(i(\xi x - \omega t))$$

into your wave equation, you find there are two frequencies of propagation for each wavenumber $\xi$:

$$\omega(\xi) = \pm \sqrt{a \xi^2 - k \xi^4}.$$

These correspond to left- and right-going waves.  To write down the full solution you need to determine which part of the initial data goes each way.  That depends on $u_t(z,0)$, which you haven't specified.  Without that information, the problem is not well-posed.